# Find the center of a .NET User Control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I'd like to display an image in the center of my user control, but I'm drawing a blank on actually "finding" the center of the control!

I feel like this should be something very simple but I just can't get my head around it.

Ideally I'd like to end up with X & Y coordinates which can be added to an instance of Point in order to display at that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2`.
You may want to add `ctrl.Left` and `ctrl.Top`.

Comment: Yea I had tried that, turned out it was my own stupidity. The item im trying to display is actually spawning a form and giving it the coords to display - to cut a long story short, it didnt work. Changed it now.

Comment: The ClientSize property should be used, makes it work even if the control has borders.

Answer (score 5):

If the image should be placed at the center, use this code:
(Pseudo, untested)

```
image.Location = new Point((control.Width / 2) - (image.Width /2),(control.Height / 2) - (image.Height / 2));
```

Comment: +1 For remembering to offset the image rather than anchoring it's top-left corner at the center.